# Why doesn't javascript redirect work?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that should redirect the user to a page when clicking the Delete button. This is the only object in the form.

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="submitbutton" id="submitbutton"  onclick="Redirect();">
```

Unfortunately the redirect is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Redirect()
{
 alert('b');
 window.location="http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
}

</script>
```

The alert is displayed. Then nothing happens. I also tried window.navigate. I am pulling my hairs out.

There is a session in the beginning of a page if that matters:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>...
```

I tried in chrome and firefox. I am clearly missing something.

Comment: Does the form have an `action` attribute?

Comment: I wonder if the form isn't being submitted. Did you try changing type=submit to type=button ?

Comment: Good point. Actually, the form was originally submitted to a php page but in this special case I need to implement an "are you sure" javascript question box so I removed the action="validate_deleteacc.php" part from the form, because with that no matter if the return of the confirm() was true or false, the form was always submitted to that php page

Comment: Maybe try `document.location.href = "http://www.tutorialspoint.com";` - Though your code *should* work if the form isn't being submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was in front of my eyes the whole time:
The accepted solution on this page:
[Try to combine javascript confirm box with php post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081016/try-to-combine-javascript-confirm-box-with-php-post-method)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably running your script and then submitting the form.

You should use:

```
<input type="button" ...>
```

Instead of:

```
<input type="submit" ...>
```